# Scroll second page from bottom to top keeping fi

Tags: html

I am working on a project where header and the full page image banner is fixed positioned.

But the challenge I am facing is I have to scroll the next div after banner up from bottom like this http://worldfitnessforever.com

How do I position my that div so that it scrolls from bottom to top keeping banner fixed at back.

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you are trying to accomplish. Would you mind explaining more, or possibly illustrating?

Comment: See here http://worldfitnessforever.com how is the page with black background coming from down when we scroll down. I just need to know how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The top header element and div ( class='container' ) will have a fixed position defined in the css. The div that appears to scroll up from the bottom will have a position set also - perhaps top:25% etc - at least that's my educated guess. Why not save the page and then analyse the html in an editor and also the css? As the page uses jQuery there is likely to be some fancy functions controlling these things but you ccould achieve it with pure css

Comment: Have set banner position as fixed. For the div to scroll from down have given the  margin-top same as the height of the banner and positioned it relative. It worked for me.